# Edit sublists of a list according to the length of the sublist

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I have a list as follows

```
{{a, b, c, d}, {e, f}, ..., 32, ..., {}, {g, h, i, j}, {k, l}, ..., 32, ..., {}, {m, n, o, p}, {q, r}. ...}
```

What I want is edit the fourth element of the bracket holding the fourth element with a constant `z` and delete every first element of the two element bracket.

I want the list to finish as follow:

> ```
> {{a, b, c, z}, {f}, ..., 32, ..., {}, {g, h, i, z}, {l}, ..., 32, ...{}, {m, n, o, z}, {r}, ...}
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list = {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f}, 32, {}, {g, h, i, j}, {k, l}, 32, {}, {m, n, o, p}, {q, r}};

list /. {{x1_, x2_, x3_, _} :> {x1, x2, x3, z}, {_, x2_} :> {x2}}
```

> {{a, b, c, z}, {f}, 32, {}, {g, h, i, z}, {l}, 32, {}, {m, n, o, z}, {r}}

Comment: worked perfectly. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 3):

I'd use rules like eldo did, but just to show another way:

```
list =
 {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f}, 32, {}, {g, h, i, j}, {k, l}, 32, {}, {m, n, o, p}, {q, r}};

p = PositionIndex[Length /@ list];

list[[p@4, 4]] = x;
list[[p@2, 1]] = Sequence[];
list = list
```

> ```
> {{a, b, c, x}, {f}, 32, {}, {g, h, i, x}, {l}, 32, {}, {m, n, o, x}, {r}}
> ```

**Note:** after `list[[. . .]] = Sequence[]` the elements have *not* been removed until `list` is evaluated, which I do with `list = list`. If you leave this out and attempt further processing on `list` directly using `Part` you may be confounded.

Answer (score 2):

quite similar to @eldo , you can use `Replace`

```
list = {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f}, 32, {}, {g, h, i, j}, {k, l}, 32, {}, {m, n, o, p}, {q, r}};

Replace[list, {{x1_, x2_, x3_, _} :> {x1, x2, x3, z}, {_, x2_} :> {x2}}, {1}]

(* {{a, b, c, z}, {f}, 32, {}, {g, h, i, z}, {l}, 32, {}, {m, n, o, z}, {r}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[f1, f2]
f1[x_] := Switch[Length @ x, 2, {Last @ x}, 4, MapAt[z &, x, {-1}], _, x]
f2[x_] := Switch[Length@x, 2, Rest, 4, MapAt[z &, -1], _, # &][x] (* thanks: Mr.Wizard *)

list = {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f}, 32, {}, {g, h, i, j}, {k, l}, 32, {}, {m, n, o, p}, {q, r}};

f1 /@ list
```

> {{a, b, c, z}, {f}, 32, {}, {g, h, i, z}, {l}, 32, {}, {m, n, o, z}, {r}}

```
% == f2 /@ list
```

> True

Comment: Another way to express this: `f1[x_] := Switch[Length@x, 2, Rest, 4, MapAt[z &, -1], _, # &][x]` -- the `Switch` returns one of three functions for each case and applies it to the argument.

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Wizard. Nice. Didn't know about the operator form of `MapAt`.